# Error while trying to replace user tags @user with link in PHP

Tags: php

This regex works fine with the words like

@user

@user.

@user.?

and other characters after @user.

But, i can't seem to get only user, without @ in my link.

```
        echo '<td>'.preg_replace('/(?<=^|\s)@(\w+)/', "<a href='usersMessages.php?id=$0'>$0</a>", $row['content'] ).'</td>';
```

Link output: .../usersMessages.php?id=@user

What I want: .../usersMessages.php?id=user

How to get rid of this?

EDIT: I tried using:

```
        echo '<td>'.preg_replace('/(?<=^|\s)@(\w+)/', "<a href='usersMessages.php?id='.str_replace('@', '', $0).''>$0</a>", $row['content'] ).'</td>';
```

but it gives me blank id: .../usersMessages.php?id=

Comment: This appears to be database-related of sorts. The `$row['content']` suggests it. Does that have value? If it doesn't, then check for errors on the query. We don't know which api you used to connect/query with. mysql_? mysqli_? PDO? If this PHP related, then add this `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` to check if there are errors. I couldn't give you the proper method / function to use for the database, because of its unknown api.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is fine, not the replacement string:

```
"<a href='usersMessages.php?id='.$row['username'].''>$row['username']</a>"
```

It seems that you're trying to concatenate inside a double quote delimited string, but you just need to enclose array items between curly brackets and remove not needed single quotes and dots:

```
"<a href='usersMessages.php?id={$row['username']}'>{$row['username']}</a>"
```

Comment: i'm sorry, i made a mistake with question. do you know how to fix my new problem perhaps? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove any character from PHP using the inbuilt function:

```
$replaced = str_replace('@', '', $yourVariable)
```

cool part about this function is it support array as well:

```
$arr = array("blue","red","green","yellow");
print_r(str_replace("red","pink",$arr,$i));
echo "Replacements: $i";
```

More can be found from [PHP Doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)